# How can I change the text for sprites from the Tic Tac Toe Unity tutorial?

Tags: unity, c#

I followed the Tic Tac Toe tutorial in unity and it works fine but I want to change the text of "X" and "O" into a sprite but I reached a dead end.

This is the player controller script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
  public Image panel;
  public Sprite playersprite;
}

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

  public Text[] buttonList;
  private string playerSide; 
  public GameObject playerX;
  public GameObject playerO;
  public GameObject gameOverPanel;
  public Text gameOverText;
  GridSpace gridspace;
  public Sprite X;
  public Sprite O;
  private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;


  public int moveCount;


  public GameObject restartButton;



  private void Awake()
  {
    gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);
    SetGameControllerReferencesOnButton();
    playerSide = "X";
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null) {
      spriteRenderer.sprite = X;
    }

    playerX.SetActive (true);
    moveCount = 0;
    restartButton.SetActive(false);
  }

  void SetGameControllerReferencesOnButton()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++)
    {
      buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<GridSpace>().SetGameControllerReference(this);
    }
  }

  public string GetPlayerSide()
  {

    return playerSide;

  }

  public void EntTurn()
  {
    moveCount++;
    if (buttonList[0].text == playerSide && buttonList[1].text == playerSide && buttonList[2].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[3].text == playerSide && buttonList[4].text == playerSide && buttonList[5].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[6].text == playerSide && buttonList[7].text == playerSide && buttonList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[0].text == playerSide && buttonList[3].text == playerSide && buttonList[6].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[1].text == playerSide && buttonList[4].text == playerSide && buttonList[7].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[2].text == playerSide && buttonList[5].text == playerSide && buttonList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[2].text == playerSide && buttonList[4].text == playerSide && buttonList[6].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    else if (buttonList[0].text == playerSide && buttonList[4].text == playerSide && buttonList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
      GameOver(playerSide);
    }

    if (moveCount > 9)
    {

      GameOver("draw");
    }
    else
    {
      ChangeSides();
    }

  }


  public void GameOver(string winningPlayer)
  {
    setBoardInter(false);
    if (winningPlayer == "draw")
    {
      setgameOverText("Try again!");
    }

    { setgameOverText(playerSide + " Wins!"); }

    restartButton.SetActive(true);
  }

  void ChangeSides()
  {
    playerSide = (playerSide == "X") ? "O" : "X";
    if (playerSide == "X") 
    {
      spriteRenderer.sprite = X;
    } else if (playerSide == "O")
    {
      spriteRenderer.sprite = O;
    }

  }

  void setgameOverText(string value)
  {
    gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
    gameOverText.text = value;
  }

  public void RestartGame()
  {
    playerSide = "X";
    moveCount = 0;
    gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++)
    {
      setBoardInter(true);
      buttonList[i].text = "";
    }
    restartButton.SetActive(false);
  }
  void setBoardInter(bool toggle)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++)
    {
      buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<Button>().interactable = toggle;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the grid space script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class GridSpace : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button button;
    public Text buttonText;
  public Sprite X;
  public Sprite O;
  private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private GameController gameController;
    public void SetSpace()
    {
        buttonText.text = gameController.GetPlayerSide();
    button.GetComponent<Sprite> ();
        button.interactable = false;
        gameController.EntTurn();
    }

    public void SetGameControllerReference(GameController controller)
    {
        gameController = controller;
    }
}
```

Comment: "reached a dead end" is very vague; what is the problem you are having? Also you should probably link to this tutorial, because I don't know what tutorial you are referencing and others might not either.

Comment: In case anyone wants to refer the tutorial, I guess this is it: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/tic-tac-toe/introduction-and-setting-project?playlist=17111